# How to find distance between two objects in free fall?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, free-fall

So if I have two exactly the same rocks and drop one then the other 2 seconds later, how would I find the distance between the two rocks when the first hits the ground? I know the height, let's say it's 40m. I want to know HOW to do this. Would I find time it takes the rocks to hit the ground first since both are the same? Then set each equal? Mostly just having issues with what equations I suppose

Comment: Hint: use $S_y = u_yt - 1/2gt^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the time it takes for the first rock to hit the ground using your constant acceleration formulas and then sub this time -2 seconds back into your formula to find the position of the second rock at that time.

Comment: Does this work though? That's what I was thinking but is it true considering distance between increases in free fall, therefore is it still 2 seconds behind when the first hits the ground?

Comment: I believe you'll find your answer here: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/distance-between-two-objects-dropped-at-different-times.432801/

Comment: As EOC suggests, do the calculation, find an answer, ask yourself if it is reasonable, then decide if the procedure works. If you are always making excuses *not* to do a calculation, you will never gain confidence in your own abilities.